# Get Olson timezone current offset

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset

In our system we have list of olson timezones, which get from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/timeZones.txt and in this data we have correct offset only for 1 January and 1 July of the year for each timezone. That means, if some of timezone offset changes by daylight saving time in, for example 2 January, i will have not correct offset for this timezone until 1 July, when i get new data..
How or where i can get actual offset for every day for olson timezone id(America/Los_Angeles, Australia/Melbourne and others from this list)..

Comment: What language / platform was this for?  The Olson db is implemented in many libraries.

Answer (score 1):

They have implemented `rawOffset` now, you should use that instead.